# meaning of verb 'come as'

Tags: verbs, idiom-meaning

How would you translate 'what have you come as?' I've never heard this expression

Comment: *Come* is a very trigger-no-metric word.

Comment: The Halloween meaning refers to a _masquerade_.  Does this meaning seem to fit? You didn't give enough context in your question for us to be sure that's the meaning.

Comment: "come as" is a phrasal verb that is used as an _idiom_. See Dog Lover's answer.

Comment: It is either literally or figuratively referring to a sort of masquerade party, where you "come as" some character.  It might be used in the figurative sense when asking someone if, for example, they have come to a meeting in their official capacity as The Not So Big Kahuna, or, perhaps, as just another programmer on the team.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I want to tell you more about the context: the question is made by a girl who meets at a party another girl who is dressed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What have you come as" can be used in party contexts, such as Halloween.

> 'What are you going to come as for Halloween?'
>
> 'I'm going to dress up as Homer Simpson.'

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't come across too many instances of "What have you come as?" in AmE.

Dog Lover's "What are you going to come as?" is plausible, but unnecessarily complex - "What are you going as?" would serve.

"What have you come as?" is more commonly expressed as, "What/Who are you supposed to be?".

It's more common in the past tense, third person: "They came as the ghosts of George and Martha Washington." (US)